# Performance data collection in Linux (API)

Tags: c++, linux, performance, perl, performance-testing

I need some library which has comprehensive set of APIs which can help to collect performance data of current machine. Could be very useful if this library written in C++ or Perl.
Tried to googling, since I don't know right terminology for that I found a lot of big and already established projects, which I cannot embed into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/index.html) Performance Application Programming Interface. It lets you collect data on all performance counters available e.g. FLOP (floating point operations) if you wish to validate your theoretical FLOP count. It also offers an API to compute MFLOPS or even find the cache hit ratio for your application. I have used the library extensively in supporting platforms in addition to [Intel VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe).

[Here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/wiki/PAPIC%3aPAPI.3#PAPI_Native_Events) is a list of "native" PAPI events but everything else you will find as CPU native counters.

Comment: thanks very much I appreciate your effort, it seems its related to applications performance, but I need current state of actual machine, like how much memory is used, CPU%, network bandwidth, etc.

Comment: I guess I will add it to my library list to investigate

Comment: It is just a matter of finding the correct performance counter. PAPI supports this natively though: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projects/papi/wiki/PAPIC:PAPI_get_dmem_info.3